# Tweepy 4.14.0 example script from Tweepy website gives AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, twitter, pip, tweepy

I am quite literally just trying to do the example from the website.  I have my relevant keys in the script below, ignoring the

Script is as follows

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key='REPLACE_ME',
                       consumer_secret='REPLACE_ME',
                       access_token='REPLACE_ME',
                       access_token_secret='REPLACE_ME')

# Replace the text with whatever you want to Tweet about
response = client.create_tweet(text='hello world')

print(response)
```

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'Client'
```

I have no idea why this would not work as such. I have no other files called tweepy, etc.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

I have reinstalled tweepy, I have force-upgraded it, I have no ideas what else could be causing this.  I'm truly befuddled.

Comment: How have you installed `tweepy`? With `pip`? What is the installed version? `pip show tweepy` ? `python -c "import tweepy; print(tweepy.__version__)"`` ?

Comment: PIP, yes, installed version shows 4.14.0.  When I run that second snippet of code I get the following error (the bottom of the stack here:   
` raise ImportError(
ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' modu                              le is compiled with 'OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017'. See: https://github.com/                              urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168 `